# Azure windows virtual machine load balance

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-machine

First I've captured image of my Azure windows virtual machine [see](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/), then I created two new virtual machines(VM1, VM2) from this captured image. Now I want to do load balancing with these 2 virtual machines [see](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/). But the "LOAD-BALANCE TRAFFIC ON AN EXISTING ENDPOINT" option is disabled (I added the endpoint in VM1) also my availability set is not showing under  "AVAILABILITY SET" option in VM2.

If I do the same process by creating virtual machine from the Gallery, and follow the steps from [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/), it worked for me.

Is there any power shell command or other way to load balance?

Please help me.

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both the virtual machines to be under the same cloud service. Only then you get the option to load balance them. There is no way add existing VMs to the same network. there are operations in the Service management API (usable through powershell) to create a new VM. You can use that to create a fresh VM from your existing image and connect it to the same service as your first VM. Then you'llhave the necessary options enabled for load balancing.

Comment: IUnknown, How can I create same file on both vms? I mean, I want to create XYZ.txt on VM1, VM2. Due to the load balancing configured the DNS is the same.

Comment: Kapil, Sorry I did not get your question. Can you elaborate by what you mean by creating same file on 2 VMs?

Comment: Actually I'm creating IIS Publish Points on my virtual machines [see this link](http://www.iis.net/learn/media/live-smooth-streaming/creating-and-managing-live-smooth-streaming-publishing-points). I want to create **XYZ.isml** file on both VM1, VM2 virtual machines. If we do not load balance them the we can create the file on both machines using VM1.Cloudapp.net, VM2.Cloudapp.net. But now vms are load balanced and the DNS becomes VM1.Cloudapp.net for both. So, in this case how can I create publish point both vms?